How can I "lock" the value of a static property inside a Task to what it was when a Task starts?
I would like to start a long-running Task which will use the value of a static property on a static class. I would like it to "capture" the value when it starts the task, and continue to use that value even if/when that static property changes "outside" the task.
MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty = "foo";
Task.Run(() => 
{
   // Assume this runs for 10 minutes...
   // MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty should continue to be "foo"
   // because that's what it was when the task started
});


MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty = "bar";
// Even though this executes milliseconds after the task starts,
// the value of this property inside the task should remain "foo"

Effectively, I want my Task to "copy" the state of this value and keep it's own version of it, isolated from what's happened "outside" the Task while it runs.
Update: I can't just make a local copy of the value, because code in the Task might call other code, which calls other code, etc. And the code that is called will have no knowledge of the local copy of the variable. Code that is X levels removed, will just be ignorantly calling MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty

Have you considered doing what you describe; copy the value and use the copy?

I can't do this, because code in the Task might call other code, which calls other code, etc. And the code that is called will have no knowledge of the local copy of the variable. It will just be ignorantly calling MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty.

Updated the question.

what about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-8.0

While you might manage a workaround with an AsyncLocal, I would still recommend that you refactor your code. As you can see, relying on static variables adds annoying complications. Though you haven't provided much context, which could change which answer is more appropriate. Perhaps you should store and supply this value using dependency injection and the options pattern?

Every time you run into this problem, you can workaround it. But trust me, in a year you will wish you did the thing you know you should really do in your heart of hearts - which is to get rid of the static altogether.

combining multi threading with global mutable state is a terrible idea, and is almost guaranteed to cause issues sooner or later. Thread safety becomes much easier when using immutable types and pure methods as much as possible.

This sounds like a solution for AsyncLocal<T>. The example on the docs explain it well.
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Example
{
    static AsyncLocal<string> _asyncLocalString = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    static async Task AsyncMethodA()
    {
        // Start multiple async method calls, with different AsyncLocal values.
        _asyncLocalString.Value = "Value 1";
        var t1 = AsyncMethodB("Value 1");

        _asyncLocalString.Value = "Value 2";
        var t2 = AsyncMethodB("Value 2");

        // Await both calls
        await t1;
        await t2;
     }

    static async Task AsyncMethodB(string expectedValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering AsyncMethodB.");
        Console.WriteLine("   Expected '{0}', AsyncLocal value is '{1}'", 
                          expectedValue, _asyncLocalString.Value);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting AsyncMethodB.");
        Console.WriteLine("   Expected '{0}', got '{1}'", 
                          expectedValue, _asyncLocalString.Value);
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await AsyncMethodA();
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//   Entering AsyncMethodB.
//      Expected 'Value 1', AsyncLocal value is 'Value 1'
//   Entering AsyncMethodB.
//      Expected 'Value 2', AsyncLocal value is 'Value 2'
//   Exiting AsyncMethodB.
//      Expected 'Value 2', got 'Value 2'
//   Exiting AsyncMethodB.
//      Expected 'Value 1', got 'Value 1'

